# Error in app delegate when trying to run on boarding

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am trying to make an onboarding screen for my iOS application using paper onboarding, which works well, but I have a problem in the `app delegate` and storyboard.

When I run my app, there is an error:

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

The simulator shows a black screen. Does this mean that the root view controller is not being set? In storyboards, I have not set an initial view controller, but when I tried setting the onboard screen as the initial view controller, the app worked, suggesting that there are no errors in the onboarding view controller.

Here is the AppDeleagte. Also, I have made sure that the storyboard ids are correct.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

  var initialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onboarding") as UIViewController

  let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

  if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "onboardingComplete") {
    initialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Mainapp") as UIViewController
  }

  self.window!.rootViewController = initialVC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

First, you haven't set your `UIWindow` as key and visible. So, add this line of code after you set your `rootViewController`:

```
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

At this point, your code will work, but the error you mentioned will probably still be output to the console when you run the app.

When you create a project, Xcode sets it up so that the `Main` storyboard is loaded automatically (displaying the initial view controller).

So, even though you're setting up the `window` yourself programatically, your app is *still* trying to launch the initial view controller in the main storyboard file, as the project settings tell it do so.

To stop it from trying to do that, open up the "General" settings of your app's target, clear out the contents of the "Main interface" text field, and hit return to save the changes.

This will update your project's `info.plist`, removing the `Main storyboard file base name` key/value which cause this automatic behaviour to occur on app launch.

Screenshot below:

[image: Update the Main interface in your target's general settings]

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot the post the `makeKeyAndVisible `. also,  i tried removing main from main interface but i still got the black screen and the same error

Comment: If you update your question with the amended code that includes the `makeKeyAndVisible` call, a screenshot of your settings, and a screenshot of your `info.plist` someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
let onboardingVC = "get your onboarding VC here"

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window.rootViewController = onboardingVC
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I hope that helps you. Comment if you face any problem. 
Happy to Help!

Answer (score -1):

It seems you missed to "return true" at the end

```
     var window: UIWindow?

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

          window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
          let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          var initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onboarding") as UIViewController
          let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
          if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "onboardingComplete") {
            initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Mainapp") as UIViewController
          }
          self.window?.rootViewController = initialVC
          return true
        }
```

UPDATE:

I recently created a new project, and seems to be faced your issue, with unability to load ViewController programmatically via AppDelegate.

Here what worked for me.
Since IOS 13 and SwiftUI, Apple introduced a new file called "SceneDelegate.swift" for supporting SwiftUI features,

So you dont need to set anything in "AppDelegate.swift", instead do this in "SceneDelegate.swift"

There is already a property for window.

> var window: UIWindow?

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   let yourVCToView = UIStoryboard.storyboardWith....()
   window?.rootViewController = yourVCToView
   guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```